# Apply function to each column of dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I have the following (very large) dataframe:

```
     id         epoch
1     0     1.141194e+12
2     1     1.142163e+12
3     2     1.142627e+12
4     2     1.142627e+12
5     3     1.142665e+12
6     3     1.142665e+12
7     4     1.142823e+12
8     5     1.143230e+12
9     6     1.143235e+12
10    6     1.143235e+12
```

For every unique ID, I now want to get the difference between its maximum and minimum time (epoch timestamp). There are IDs with many more occurences than in the example above, in case it is relevant. I haven't worked much with R yet and tried the following:

```
unique = data.frame(as.numeric(unique(df$id)))
differences = apply(unique, 1, get_duration)

get_duration = function(id) {
  maxTime = max(df$epoch[which(df$id == id)])
  minTime = min(df$epoch[which(df$id == id)])
  return ((maxTime - minTime) / 1000)
}
```

It works, but is incredibly slow. What would be a faster approach?

Comment: Please notice that you are hiding the `unique` function, which you also use. This is something to be careful and to avoid. Check the existing `conflicts()`.

Comment: Also `tapply(df$epoch,df$id,function(x) max(x)-min(x))`.

Comment: @nicola wouldn't it actually be `tapply(df$epoch, df$id, function(x) (max(x)-min(x))/1000)` to match OP's original function?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Yes, I guess you are right. Another approach with `data.table`: `setDT(df);df[,list(d=(max(epoch)-min(epoch))/1000),by=id]`

Comment: Thank you, tapply is what I was looking for! However, I don't understand what you mean by hiding the unique function - can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of approaches. In base `R`:

```
tapply(df$epoch,df$id,function(x) (max(x)-min(x))/1000)
```

With `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,list(d=(max(epoch)-min(epoch))/1000),by=id]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily in `dplyr`

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(diff=(max(epoch)-min(epoch))/1000)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the filter by id just once

```
subset = df$epoch[which(df$id == id)]
maxTime = max(subset)
minTime = min(subset)
```

Comment: This is an optimization, but not at the scale as some of the comments above that utilize the `apply` family. `tapply` is the answer here.